# Return list of mapped classes - Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this class that is linked to a View in the SQL Server:

```
[Table("V_Clients")]
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public short BranchId { get; set; }
    public string CorporateName { get; set; }
    public string TIN { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }//NroCi
    public short CityId { get; set; }
    public short ZoneId { get; set; }
    public short SubZoneId { get; set; }
    public short VendorId { get; set; }
    public short PriceListId { get; set; }
    public short CollectorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BranchId")]
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ZoneId")]
    public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubZoneId")]
    public virtual SubZone SubZone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VendorId")]
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriceListId")]
    public virtual PriceList PriceLists {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("CollectorId")]
    public virtual Collector Collector { get; set; }
}
```

but when I try to make a list of it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var clients = db.Clients.Include(c => c.Branch).Include(c => c.City).Include(c => c.Zone).Include(c => c.SubZone).Include(c => c.Vendor).Include(c => c.PriceLists).Include(c => c.Collector);
        return View(clients.ToList());
    }
```

nothing happens. Could it be because of the relationships?

Note: All classes are linked to views and work fine with the others except my `Client` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing a string to Include().  Ex:

`var clients = db.Clients.Include("Branch").Include("City");`

Comment: I've tried almost everything and I end up with the conclusion: "Isn't healthy map entity framework with views".

Solved.